# Magento Cant select options on ajax quickview for configurable product

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

I'm having a problem to select a option for a configurable product on magento showing on a quick view window:

the errors:
1 - this one occurs when I use the select to change the option:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: optionsPrice is not defined configurable.js:286**

```
optionsPrice.changePrice('config', {'price': price, 'oldPrice': oldPrice});
```

2 - this one occurs when I click on the color swatch option:

**ReferenceError {stack: (...), message: "spConfig is not defined"}  colorswatch.js:221**

```
try{
    spConfig.configureElement(document.getElementById(selectId));               
    spConfig.reloadPrice();
}catch(e){
    console.debug(e);
}
```

I tried defining spConfig and Option Price all way around, but it seems out of scope, I don't know, because I can console.log both variables, but even successfully logging them I get these errors.

I loaded configurable.js and product.js on category view successfully.

some more code:

configurable.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof optionsPrice === 'undefined' ){
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
}
console.log(optionsPrice); // logs the variable just fine
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    console.log(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>); // logs fine
    console.log(spConfig); // here too
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        IWD.ColorSwatch.configAttributes = '<?php echo $_switchHelper->getJsonConfig($_product)?>';
        IWD.ColorSwatch.config = '<?php echo $_switchHelper->getJsonModuleConfig()?>';
        IWD.ColorSwatch.init();
    });
</script>
```

This is the link for the site: [HERE](http://bazis.com.br/store/roupas/vestidos.html)

If you need more code, just ask that I'll add it here!

Thanks!!!!

**EDIT**
I'm using a custom quick view module https://github.com/czettnersandor/magento-quick-view-ajax

Comment: What quick view window are you talking about? Sounds like you used a custom module for this function.

Comment: Yes, I've used this quick view module https://github.com/czettnersandor/magento-quick-view-ajax

Comment: Having the same issue here, did you get it resolved?